# /usr/bin/fg: line 4: fg: no job control

Tags: path, executable, job-control

I have faced the problem mentioned above when I call

```
sleep 100 &
```

Background job starts, and then I pause the process by:

```
kill -STOP <PID>
```

Then if I just say

```
fg sleep
```

It brings the job to foreground and running state. However

```
/usr/bin/fg sleep
```

gives an error. I checked the path of fg with

```
which fg
whereis fg
```

And both give: `/usr/bin/fg`

How can I fix this? Also, I am trying to call fg with execvp in C and I need to figure out this issue.

Comment: Just run `cat /usr/bin/fg` and you'll find some enlightment.

Comment: `fg` is a shell built-in; when you run `fg sleep` you are NOT running the `/usr/bin/fg` stub (which would NOT able to mess with your shell's job table), but the shell's `fg` builtin. `whereis` and `which` are not the right tool to determine whether a command is a builtin, function or external program.

Comment: @mosvy Then how can I use fg with 'execvp'

Comment: And exec-ing that dummy stub from C will not help you implement the job control in your shell. Please take some time to read about all that [stuff](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html); poking in the dark won't get you anywhere near it.

Comment: You cannot use `fg` with `execvp`; in fact, you can try, but it will only print an error message, nothing more.

Comment: But then how should I manage jobs in my own shell?

Comment: You have a whole [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html#Implementing-a-Shell) in the link I gave you above. Basically you should both continue a job with `kill(SIGCONT)` and make it the foreground job with `tcsetpgrp()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am going to check that tutorial carefully

Comment: @Quasímodo `type -a fg` yields in
`type: bad option(s) -a
usage: type [-F] [name ...]` type -a in an extension that is not portable.